# How to unregister the assembly registered using regasm

Tags: dll, asp-classic, dllregistration

I registered one of my dlls on the development machine using regasm as below (ASP application)

In a cmd prompt, I navigated to 
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 and did:

```
regasm /tlb "xxx.dll"
```

Now I made some changes in the dll. So I unregistered the dll using the command:

```
regasm /u xxx.dll /tlb:xxx.tlb
```

Then I registered the updated dll again with previous command. But the changes are not coming up in the project, so I doubt it's still pointing to the old dll. I restarted the machine, but that did not help.
So:

1. What are the ways to make sure my old dll is removed and the current one is new?
2. Is there any physical path to check them manually?

**UPDATE:** The below solution fixed the issue.

To Register:

```
SET WorkFolder= '<directory>'
regasm.exe %WorkFolder%\xxx.dll /Codebase
```

To unregister.

```
SET WorkFolder= '<directory>'
regasm.exe /unregister %WorkFolder%\xxx.dll
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try

```
regasm /u "[full path to your DLL in double quotes]"
```

To re-register use

```
regasm /codebase "[full path to your DLL in double quotes]"
```

ignore the warning.

Comment: Regasm is located at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.

Comment: Depending on the version of Windows, `RegAsm.exe` may instead be located elsewhere.  For example, `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and/or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`.