# Register Com c# BHO DLL using NSIS

Tags: c#, dll, com, nsis, bho

First of all i am new to windows programming, sorry for using any wrong terminologies.
I have created a c# BHO and i am able to register dll through Visual Studio Command Prompt(Run as Administrator) using below command on windows 7 64-bit.

```
regasm.exe HelloBHOWorld1.dll /codebase
```

as mention in this question [How to unregister the assembly registered using regasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841428/how-to-unregister-the-assembly-registered-using-regasm)

This my RegisterBHO and UnregisterBHO method.

```
public static string BHOKEYNAME =
  "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";

    [ComRegisterFunction]
    public static void RegisterBHO(Type type)
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHOKEYNAME, true);

        if (registryKey == null)
            registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(BHOKEYNAME);

        string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
        RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid);

        if (ourKey == null)
            ourKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);

        ourKey.SetValue("Alright", 1);
        registryKey.Close();
        ourKey.Close();
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunction]
    public static void UnregisterBHO(Type type)
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHOKEYNAME, true);
        string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

        if (registryKey != null)
            registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
    }
```

I am creating exe using NSIS to register BHO during installation. I tried below commands one by one in NSIS to register it.

```
ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\regsvr32.exe" /s "$INSTDIR\ie\HelloBHOWorld.dll"'
ExecWait 'regasm.exe "$INSTDIR\ie\HelloBHOWorld.dll" /register /codebase /tlb'
RegDLL "$INSTDIR\ie\HelloBHOWorld1.dll"
ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\rundll32.exe" $INSTDIR\ie\HelloBHOWorld.dll DllRegisterServer'
```

Nothing is working for me. What am i doing wrong? What is correct way?

Comment: Only the second is correct of course.  Your registration functions are nonsense, was that intentional?  What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: You are [not supposed to](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/22/10396079.aspx) write BHOs in managed code...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I follow this article [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350432/BHO-Development-using-managed-code) to create BHO. That why i wrote these methods. But this **ExecWait 'regasm.exe "$INSTDIR\ie\HelloBHOWorld.dll" /register /codebase /tlb'** command is not working for me. Do you want to suggest me any modification in it?

Answer (score 0):

The `ExecWait` NSIS instruction just uses the `CreateProcess()` and `WaitForSingleObject()` WinAPI functions so you can probably run regasm.exe manually first to make sure that is actually working.

You can try to see where it goes wrong (cannot load dll? cannot write to the registry?) with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)...